# What if I want to make this class as a list in java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I've just made this simple student program which reads the data and writes into the file.

What I need is if I want to enter 100 data of students how to make it in a list and that should be from user side

For example,

Enter students you want to enter : 2

Name : Satish devnani
Roll No : 1

Name : Sonu
Roll No : 2

And if user enters 100 then it should be 100.

made until this :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


class filesatish2{

    String name;
    int number;
    //int i=0;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        //int i;
        filesatish2 stname= new filesatish2();      
        Students.READ();    
        Students.FILEWRITE();
    }

    int HOWMANY()
    {
        int count;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        printit("How many data you want to enter ?");
        count=sc.nextInt();
        //printit(""+count);
        return count;
    }

    void READ() 
    {               
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner text=new Scanner(System.in);

        printit("Name   :");
        name=text.nextLine();

        printit("Number     :");
        number=sc.nextInt();
    }

    public static void printit(String a) 
    {
        System.out.print(a);        
    }

     public void FILEWRITE() throws IOException 
     {  
        File student = new File("Student.txt");
        FileWriter printer = new FileWriter(student);
        student.createNewFile();

        printer.write(""+name);
        printer.write("\t"+number);

        printer.flush();
        printer.close();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class filesatish2 {
    List studentList = new ArrayList();
    String name;
    int number;
    int count = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        // int i;
        filesatish2 stname = new filesatish2();
        stname.count = stname.HOWMANY();
        stname.READ();
        stname.FILEWRITE();
    }

    int HOWMANY() {
        int count;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        printit("How many data you want to enter ?");
        count = sc.nextInt();
        // printit(""+count);
        return count;

    }

    void READ() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner text = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            printit("Name   :");
            name = text.nextLine();
            printit("Number     :");
            number = sc.nextInt();

            studentList.add(name + "\t" + number + "\n");
        }

    }

    public static void printit(String a) {
        System.out.print(a);
    }

    public void FILEWRITE() throws IOException {
        File student = new File("Student.txt");
        FileWriter printer = new FileWriter(student);
        student.createNewFile();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            printer.write((String) studentList.get(i));
        }

        printer.flush();
        printer.close();
    }

}
```